# How to import packages in within a lambda expression?

Tags: python-3.x, lambda

My friend who is new to Python wants to create a function that returns the probability of getting at least a six face when rolling n dices m times.

Instead of the boring `P = 1-(5./6)**n`, I decided to scare him the following as a practical joke:

```
import random
throw_dice = lambda n, m: round(sum(any(random.randint(1,6) == 6 for die in range(n)) for trial in range(m))/m,5)
```

Is it possible for me to compress it even more by combining `import random` into the lambda expression so that i end up with only one line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do only want 1 line of code, you could use a semicolon like so:

`import random; throw_dice = lambda n, m: round(sum(any(random.randint(1,6) == 6 for die in range(n)) for trial in range(m))/m,5)`

Comment: I guess that works but using a semicolon makes it technically 2 lines

Comment: @JoeAverage I am pretty sure the only way you can achieve this is with a semicolon.